# How to use PowerShell to set the time on a remote device?

Tags: powershell, raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I want to set the Date and Time of a remote device (*Raspberry Pi 2 running Windows IoT*) to the value of the Date Time of a local device.

I create a variable $dateTime to hold the local DateTime.
I assign a password to connect to  a remote device to a variable $password.
I create a credential object.
I connect to the remote device using Enter-PSSession.
Now that I'm connected I try assigning the remote devices DateTime using Set-Date = $dateTime | Out-String.

I get *cannot convertvalue "=" to type "System.TimeSpan"* error.

```
$dateTime = Get-Date
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("myremotedevice     \Administrator",$password)
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName myremotedevice -Credential $cred
Set-Date = $dateTime | Out-String
```

It seems as if the $dateTime variable is out of scope once I am connected via the PSSession.  Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use Enter-PSSession for this at all, since that's for interactive sessions.

I'd use this:

```
$dateTime = Get-Date;
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force;
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("myremotedevice     \Administrator",$password);
Invoke-Command -ComputerName myremotedevice -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Date -Date $using:datetime;
}
```

Or, if I had multiple things to execute:

```
$dateTime = Get-Date;
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force;
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("myremotedevice     \Administrator",$password);
$session = New-PsSession -ComputerName -Credential $cred;
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Date -Date $using:datetime;
}
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { [...] }
.
.
Disconnect-PsSession -Session $session;
```

[Passing local variables to a remote session](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/01/23/pstip-passing-local-variables-to-a-remote-session-in-powershell-3-0/) usually requires the `using` namespace.

Comment: I will give it a try and report back.  Thanks Bacon Bits,