# Sending message to Azure Iot Hub from Raspberry

Tags: c#, azure, win-universal-app, raspberry-pi2

I need to send a message to Azure Iot Hub (https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/services/iot-hub/) from an Universal App installed in my Raspberry. I've to use HTTP protocol because Raspberry doesn't supports AMQP.
I use the following code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private DispatcherTimer _timer = null;
    private DeviceClient _deviceClient = null;
    private const string _deviceConnectionString = "<myConnectionString>";

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_deviceConnectionString, TransportType.Http1);

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private async void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        string msg = "{deviceId: 'myFirstDevice', timestamp: " + DateTime.Now.Ticks + " }";

        Message eventMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg));
        await _deviceClient.SendEventAsync(eventMessage);
    }
}
```

`SendEventAsync` gives me:

`Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions.IotHubCommunicationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll`

```
Message: {"An error occurred while sending the request."}
```

I've included in my project `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` as documented here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/issues/65 with no results.

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client": "1.0.0-preview-007",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0"
 },
"frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
}
```

**If I try the SAME code in a Console application it works as expected.**

Comment: What kind of capabilities does your project have?

Comment: Only `Internet (Client)`

Comment: Could you try to send events by hand using this code:
https://github.com/danvy/sigfox/blob/master/src/SigfoxEventSimulator/Program.cs
Your can create your SAS Token using this tool: 
http://danvy.tv/sas-token-generator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching I found an hardware problem. My Raspberry was trying to use the non-configured Wi-Fi dongle to send the request while for all other requests used the network cable. Removing the dongle did the trick.

Comment: On this note, I find that my pi gets confused if it has multiple networks connections to choose from.

Comment: You can have the same issue if the internal raspberry datime is not set to now! Mine was 2h in the past! Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828332/how-to-use-powershell-to-set-the-time-on-a-remote-device

Answer (score 0):

@danvy is right you need to generate a SAS token,here is a signature generator https://github.com/sandrinodimattia/RedDog/releases

There could be multiple ways to send events, you are using http, check out this sample

```
// Generate a SAS key with the Signature Generator.: 
var sas = "SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3a%2f%2freddogeventhub.servicebus.windows.net%2ftemperature%2fpublishers%2flivingroom%2fmessages&sig=I7n%2bqlIExBRs23V4mcYYfYVYhc6adOlMAeTY9VM9kNg%3d&se=1405562228&skn=SenderDevice";

// Namespace info.
var serviceNamespace = "myeventhub";  
var hubName = "temperature";  
var deviceName = "livingroom";

// Create client.
var httpClient = new HttpClient();  
httpClient.BaseAddress =  
           new Uri(String.Format("https://{0}.servicebus.windows.net/", serviceNamespace));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders  
           .TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", sas);

Console.WriteLine("Starting device: {0}", deviceName);

// Keep sending.
while (true)  
{
    var eventData = new
    {
        Temperature = new Random().Next(20, 50)
    };

    var postResult = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(
           String.Format("{0}/publishers/{1}/messages", hubName, deviceName), eventData).Result;

    Console.WriteLine("Sent temperature using HttpClient: {0}", 
           eventData.Temperature);
    Console.WriteLine(" > Response: {0}", 
           postResult.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine(" > Response Content: {0}", 
           postResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

    Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(1000, 5000));
}
```

Check out this article for more details http://fabriccontroller.net/iot-with-azure-service-bus-event-hubs-authenticating-and-sending-from-any-type-of-device-net-and-js-samples/

Comment: I'm using the new Azure IoT Hub (https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/services/iot-hub/) and I followed the getting started guide from Microsoft here: https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/develop/iot/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

try to set a connection string to your device (_deviceConnectionString) using this tutorial

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/tools/DeviceExplorer/doc/how_to_use_device_explorer.md

You can do it by hand using the information you get from the IoT Hub directly or from the dashboard created by the IoT Suite wizard. It will look like this

_deviceConnectionString = "HostName=YourIoTHubName.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=YourDeviceId;SharedAccessKey=YourDeviceSharedAccessKey";

Comment: Connection string works properly using the same code in a Console Application.

Comment: Does your app runs on your PC?

Comment: I've added the solution. It was an hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate the DeviceId and device key correctly using CreateDeviceIdentity tool? 
Here is the guide: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/12/09/windows-iot-core-and-azure-iot-hub-putting-the-i-in-iot/

Comment: Followed article step-by-step, copy-pasted the code and same error! `An error occurred while sending the request.` Inner exception is: `{"Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072F05"}`

Comment: Can you share the code with me on GitHub or somewhere?

Comment: I added the solution, it was an hardware problem. Thanks